# Summarize time series

Tags: r, time-series, summary

I am trying to summarize a dataset with that is a time series of data on multiple different EU's.   the device records data every 15minutes but I would like it summarized for analysis into different time intervals of hourly,6hour and daily intervals.  I have been through several posts on the list and have had no luck.  Any help would be appreciated.

Example data is below

```
Signal  Date         Timedate              ID  Tx  Block
49     2014-08-14   08/14/2014 21:00:00   15   1   1
35     2014-08-14   08/14/2014 21:15:00   15   1   1
149    2014-08-14   08/14/2014 21:30:00   15   1   1
135    2014-08-14   08/14/2014 21:45:00   15   1   1
```

In this form for about 70k more records.   Data needs to be condense into 1 record for each 4 entries (for hourly) and so forth with the total of signal summed.

Final output

```
Signal  Date         Timedate              ID  Tx  Block
368    2014-08-14   08/14/2014 21:00:00   15   1   1
```

Comment: So, just to be clear and to offer a search hint: you want  sums of "Signal" `aggregate()`-ed within categories of "ID", "tx", and "Block" and you want the time blocks labeled with starting times?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a quick `data.table` wrap up, but you could do it similarly with base R. In short, all you need to do is to convert `Timedate` to a `POSIXct` class while removing minutes and seconds, and then a simple aggregate

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, Timedate := as.POSIXct(substr(Timedate, 1, 19), format = "%m/%d/%Y %H")]
df[, .(Signal = sum(Signal)), by = .(Date, Timedate, ID, Tx, Block)]
#          Date            Timedate ID Tx Block Signal
# 1: 2014-08-14 2014-08-14 21:00:00 15  1     1    368
```

The aggregation part could be done eaisly with base R too, just

```
aggregate(Signal ~., df, sum)
#         Date            Timedate ID Tx Block Signal
# 1 2014-08-14 2014-08-14 21:00:00 15  1     1    368
```

---

Another option (if the data is sorted and always has intervals of 4) you could create an index and aggregate by it without modifying `Timedate` in the original data

```
setDT(df)[, indx := gl(nrow(df)/4, nrow(df)/4)]
df[, .(Signal = sum(Signal), Timedate = Timedate[1L]),  by = .(Date, ID, Tx, Block, indx)]
#          Date ID Tx Block indx Signal            Timedate
# 1: 2014-08-14 15  1     1    1    368 08/14/2014 21:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
library(zoo)
?aggregate.zoo
examples(aggregate.zoo)
```

you need to study it a bit, but it is powerful.